# problemas ao redimensionar um elemento

Tags: css, html5, css3, flexbox

Estou fazendo uns testes com flexbox e me deparei com um certo problema. Ao definir o body como flex, as divs dentro do section não se redimensionam ao definirmos seu tamanho com o width. Mas se retirarmos o flex do body, o redimensionamento ocorre.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .container {
        flex: 0 1 960px;
        display: flex;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: tomato;
      }
      body {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
      }
      .primeiro {
        margin-left: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 250px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: turquoise;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="container">
      <div class="primeiro">ola</div>
      <div class="primeiro">hy</div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128633/discussion-between-flexuser-and-hozeis).

Comment: Para prosseguir com a dúvida é importante [edit] e trocar o código por um [mcve] do problema. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Vamo la.  O seu código original:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .container {
        flex: 0 1 960px;
        display: flex;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: tomato;
      }
      body {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
      }
      .primeiro {
        margin-left: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 250px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: turquoise;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="container">
      <div class="primeiro">ola</div>
      <div class="primeiro">hy</div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Essa versão do seu código não redimensiona pq quando voce coloca `display: flex` dentro do `body` voce esta definindo que os components dentro do `body` devem ser organizar dentro de um `row` com um tamanho predeterminado de `960px` que voce determina quando defini o valor `flex: 0 1 960px;` dentro do container. Então se voce minimizar a tela ele sempre vai ficar com um tamanho fixo de `960px`.

[jsfiddle - primeira versão do código](https://jsfiddle.net/x0gmjdyu/4/)

**Agora quando voce muda seu código para:**

```
.container { 
/* flex: 0 1 960px;  */
display: flex; 
height: 300px; 
margin: 0 auto; 
max-width: 960px; 
background-color: tomato; 
} 
body { 
height: 100vh; 
width: 100%;
/* display: flex; */
}
```

Voce esta removendo `display: flex`, isso remove aquele tamanho determinado de `960px`, liberando o `<section class="container">` a minimizar.  Se voce for e coloca `minWidth: 960` dentro da classe `container` vc vai ver que ele compacta da mesma forma de quando estava com `display:flex` dentro do `body`.

Nesse ponto se voce minimizar a tela o bastante voce ver que os itens `.primeiros` começam a mudar de tamanho.  Mais isso e pq voce tem esta usando o valor `flex` dentro do `.container` e ele ta mantendo os valores dentro de um `row` dentro do tamanho da tela que esta como `100%`.  `margin-left` também toma preferencia do que o espaço vazio dentro do div.

Acredito que isso e sua pergunta. Se quiser mais clarificao me manda uma mensagem que atualizo a resposta.

Comment: vi sua resposta achei bastante interessante. Mas me gera uma divida que é, se o container tem um flex: 0 1 960px, quer dizer que o shirink está ativado e o container pode diminuir, mas pq seus filhos .primeiro não podem ?

Comment: O valor `flex: 0 1 960px` e uma propriedade de `.container` e não e repassado para `.primeiro`.  Se voce queria passar a capacidade de minimizar para os componente "filhos" de `.container`.  Troca `width` de `.primeiro` para `flex: 0 1 250px;` e voce vai vai diminuir também.